# What is advantage of throwing InvalidArgumentException instead Exception?

Tags: php, exception

I wonder what is advantage of using InvalidArgumentException instead Exception? 
Does it for increasing code readibility or there are another reasons for that?

```
public function setShortName($shortName){
    $shortName = (string) $shortName;
    if (strlen( $shortName ) == 2) {
        $this->_shortName = (string) $shortName;
    } else {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException( "Ülke kısa ismi 2 karakterden oluşmak zorundadır", 115003 );
    }
}
```

or

```
public function setShortName($shortName){
    $shortName = (string) $shortName;
    if (strlen( $shortName ) == 2) {
        $this->_shortName = (string) $shortName;
    } else {
        throw new Exception( "Ülke kısa ismi 2 karakterden oluşmak zorundadır", 115003 );
    }
}
```

Comment: its for better readability/debugging and for processing right branch of code e.g. in try-catch block

Comment: and you can use multiple catch blocks for error handling with different types of exception..

Comment: I agree with you it will help me to handling exceptions in catch blocks..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's for better readability/debugging and for processing right block of code e.g. in try-catch block...

```
try {
  // some code with potential exception throwing block
} catch(InvalidArgumentException $ex) {
  // handling InvalidArgumentException
} catch(AnotherException $ex) {
  // handling AnotherException
} catch(Exception $ex) {
  // handling Exception
} finally {
  // always-processed code
}
```

Note that exceptions have tree-based structure so handling depends on their order! (from lowest to root)

[image]

for more information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-tree.html

Comment: Would the `catch(Exception $ex)` catch the `InvalidArgumentException` if there was no `catch(InvalidArgumentException $ex)` block?

Comment: yes, because `Exception` is a parent of `InvalidArgumentException` exceptions are tree-based structure (and `Exception` is the root)